# upload and preview file and store in database with php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli

Using the following script I'm trying to :

1. Upload an image
2. Preview the preview
3. Move the file to the folder
4. Load the name on the database.

Everything works correctly but the image name is not uploaded to the database. I do not understand the error, can someone help me?
Thank you.

```
<!--script view preview image-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#image')
            .attr('src', e.target.result)
            .width(200)
            .height();
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
<!-- /script view preview image-->

<!--html form-->
<form action="nuovo-articolo.php?start=1" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
      <label>Upload image</label>
      <label>(Max 300Kb - jpg, jpeg, png)</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="file" name="image" onchange="readURL(this);" />
    </div><!-- /upload image -->

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
      <label>Anteprima</label>
      <p><img id="image" src="#" alt="Immagine" /></p>
    </div><!-- /preview image -->
  </div><!-- /row -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Inserisci" name="submit" />
    </div><!-- /submit -->
  </div><!-- /row -->
</form><!-- /form -->
<!--html form-->

<!-- php -->
<?php
//store img name file into database
if (!empty ($_GET["start"]) ) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO articoli
    (image)
    VALUES
    (
    '".$_POST["image"]."'
    )";

  //upload file into folder
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
             $errors= array();
             $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
             $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
             $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
             $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
             $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));
       //file extension check
             $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

             if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
                    $errors[]="I formati accettati sono JPEG o PNG.";
             }
       //file dimension check
             if($file_size > 301000){
                    $errors[]='La dimensione del file non deve superare 300Kb';
             }
       //move file into folder
             if(empty($errors)==true){
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"../../uploads/articoli/".$file_name);
                    echo "File caricato";
             }else{
                    print_r($errors);
             }
        }
    //redirect
        header('Location: giacenze.php');
    } else {
        echo "Errore: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
?>
<!-- /php -->
```

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: Does the IF statement meet the condition? Does your URL contains any "start" attribute?

Comment: as written in the post, I display the preview, the image is inserted in the folder but not in the database.
I've added the start condition for security and it certainly appears in the url, see action attribute in the form tag.
I can not understand why the image name is not inserted in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please insert the image name when you move the file to folder. Here you get the $filename.

//move file into folder

if(empty($errors)==true){

```
  move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"../../uploads/articoli/".$file_name);
  echo "File caricato";
  $sql = "INSERT INTO articoli (image) VALUES ('".file_name."' )";
```

}

Comment: Now everything works perfectly, thanks for the help!